# Navigate to body of table with Web Scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get data from a website to my excel sheet but somehow I cannot navigate to the body of the table no matter what I do. Please see the website and the code below and tell me how can I get the latest values of 1Y, 2Y, ... , 10Y into my excel sheet. This is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub updatePKRV()

Dim ieobj As InternetExplorer
Dim iedoc As HTMLDocument
Dim htmlele As IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLRow As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLIT As IHTMLElement
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ieobj = New InternetExplorer
ieobj.Visible = False
ieobj.navigate "https://fma.com.pk/index.php/pkrv/"

Do While ieobj.Busy = True Or ieobj.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Loop

Set iedoc = ieobj.document
Set htmlele = iedoc.getElementById("table_2")
'Set HTMLRow = htmlele.getElementsByTagName("tr")

Debug.Print htmlele.Children(0).textContent

End Sub
```

[image]

AFTER CHANGES

```
Option Explicit

Sub updatePKRV()

Dim ieobj As InternetExplorer
Dim iedoc As HTMLDocument
Dim htmlele As IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLRow As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLIT As IHTMLElement
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long, arr()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ieobj = New InternetExplorer
ieobj.Visible = False
ieobj.navigate "https://fma.com.pk/index.php/pkrv/"

Do While ieobj.Busy = True Or ieobj.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Loop

Set iedoc = ieobj.document
Set htmlele = iedoc.getElementById("table_2")

Set nodeList = ieobj.document.querySelectorAll("#table_2 tr:nth-of-type(2) .column-date,  #table_2 tr:nth-of-type(2) [class*=y]")

ReDim arr(1 To 11)
For i = 0 To 10
    arr(i + 1) = nodeList.Item(i).innerText ''This is where is gets an error
Next

ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr, 2)) = arr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the "header" first date column and then the first 10 of the years columns within the second row. You can use a css selector for that

```
#table_2 tr:nth-of-type(2) .column-date,  #table_2 tr:nth-of-type(2) [class*=y]
```

This will retrieve a node list for the second row

```
tr:nth-of-type(2)
```

within the table with id `table_2`

```
#table_2
```

matching on the child with class `column-date`

```
.column-date
```

OR (`,`)

class that contains (`*`) the letter y (for year)

```
[class*=y]
```

Note:

1. I am matching on a single class of the multi-valued classes present.
2. The page is slow loading so you may need a timed loop to wait for elements to be fully loaded.

With that nodeList you want to go from 0 to 10 in order to get the first date field and the 10 first years.

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long, arr()

Set nodeList = ie.document.querySelectorAll("#table_2 tr:nth-of-type(2) .column-date,  #table_2 tr:nth-of-type(2) [class*=y]")

ReDim arr(1 To 11)
For i = 0 To 10
    arr(i+1) = nodeList.item(i).innerText   
Next

ActiveSheet.Cells(2,1).Resize(1, UBound(arr, 1)) = arr
```

---

Read about css selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

---

Quick browser test of matches and output:

[image]

---

2021-03-05 update

```
#table_2 tbody tr:nth-of-type(1) .column-date,  #table_2  tbody tr:nth-of-type(1) [class*=y]
```

To take first row within table body (i.e. exclude header row and obtain latest date)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I changed the code to look something like this but it gives a Runtime error '424' object required. Please see the question again. I have edited it with your code. Thanks a lot

Comment: Oops. Old habits. `ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr, 1)) = arr`

Comment: hi again. It worked perfectly well this time. But now since the website is updated, it should pick up the latest data available in the second row but its not.

Comment: `#table_2 tbody tr:nth-of-type(1) .column-date,  #table_2  tbody tr:nth-of-type(1) [class*=y]`